# Cassandra: is it possible to prohibit USE and DESCRIBE on a specific keyspaces

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cqlsh

I want to prohibit a non super role (or a specific role) to use the command 'USE' and 'DESCRIBE' on a specific keyspace. I found nothing about it ..

by the way, may I have some advise about security on cassandra ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Justy FYI: DSE 6.0+ has such functionality: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/secSystemKeyspaces.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can block read or write access to a keyspace with

```
GRANT SELECT ON KEYSPACE <yourkeyspace> TO <user>;
GRANT MODIFY ON KEYSPACE <yourkeyspace> TO <user>;
```

see http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cql/security.html (with `CassandraRoleManager`).  But `DESCRIBE` is not something you can block since that query is actually not going to C* at all but instead handled by the drivers client side (and only the python and java drivers). The drivers pull information from the system_schema keyspace (or system.schema_* in 2.1 or whatever the specific version has) and reverse engineer the DDL.

Comment: do you mean REVOKE instead of GRANT ? because GRANT allow something to the user, no ?? thanks for your help

Comment: right, create a user and by default it wont have access, grant on the resources you want to allow that user to use. If you want to remove access previously given you can revoke (assuming this is version >= 2.2)